# My file upload scenarios are passing on my local but failing on Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, file-upload

I am running my scenarios on Jenkins with EC2. My `fileUpload` scenarios are failing on Jenkins. I believe it's due to file location path but I am not sure which path I should give for EC2- Jenkins

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found : /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton/src/test.Files/putty.exe
  (Session info: headless chrome=106.0.5249.119)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ip-10-1-1-182.ec2.internal', ip: '10.1.1.182', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.118-111.515.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

My code snippet

```
public void sendPNGFileUpload() {
     Driver.wait(2);
     driver.findElement(chooseFileButton).sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test.Files/BUG PnUMBER CHAR.png");
Driver.wait(2);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the file you want to upload into the directory `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton/src/test.Files/` on the EC2 instance. So you will not need to change anything in your code.
`/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton` is the root directory of the Jenkins job. For convenience it's better to store all the files your tests may need somewhere inside this directory. And `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HE_HQ_Automaton/src/test.Files/` is a good place for these files.
And I looked once more at the question. Pay attention to the fact that the error says about the file `putty.exe` but you are showing the code for the file `BUG PnUMBER CHAR.png`. It may turn out that you are trying to solve the problem in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you @Eugeny. I will do that and add all my file paths to my EC2 instance.